# In GeoDMS, the cdf does not seem to work within the for_each command

Tags: foreach, geodms

In GeoDMS, I use a for_each_nedvc in which the c stands for cdf, however, this does not seem to work.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

```
container Positief := 
    for_each_nedvc(
    , OntwikkelPakketten/name
    , 'Value(Winst/'+OntwikkelPakketten/name+' / float32(IsPositief/'+OntwikkelPakketten/name+'), Eur)'
    , domain
    , Eur
    , 'Classified_per_OP/'+OntwikkelPakketten/name+'/Target_9K/ClassBreaks'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cdf and url properties cannot be set by a specific `for_each` operation, but can be set by the generic `for_each_ind` (with indirect property specification).

For example:

```
  container Positief :=
      for_each_ind('nedvc'
                , OntwikkelPakketten/name
                , 'Value(Winst/'+OntwikkelPakketten/name+' / float32(IsPositief/'+OntwikkelPakketten/name+'), Eur)'
                , domain
                , Eur
                , 'Classified_per_OP/'+OntwikkelPakketten/name+'/Target_9K/ClassBreaks'
  );
```

See also: http://www.objectvision.nl/geodms/operators-a-functions/metascript/for-each-indirect